# Jsoup, получить text() только родителя

Tags: java, jsoup

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить `text()` только из родителя, не включая детей?
Пример:

```
<p>
<img>100x100</img>
вот такая картинка
</р>
```

Если выделить тег `<р>` и вызвать метод `text()`, то выведет `100х100 вот такая картинка`, мне же надо просто `вот такая картинка`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Просто уберите ненужный тег:

```
Element p = ...;
p.remove(p.getElementsByTagName("img").first());
System.out.println(p.text());
```

код не проверял, методы могут немного по другому быть названы.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь [`Element.ownText()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText--)